# Java Stream Collect() classifier can't detect type

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I have the following code reading lines from a text file:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Uio.decodeFrom(url)))) {
        return br.lines()
                .parallel()
                .map(s -> s.split("\\s+")) // split by whitespace
                .collect(
                        Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(
                                arr -> arr[0], // String 1
                                Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(
                                        arr -> arr[arr.length-1], // String 2
                                        Collectors.counting()
                                )
                        )
                );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
```

The text file has data like

```
String1     ... cols      ... String2
string1data ... otherdata ... string2data
...
```

And I'm trying to group by `String1` and `String2` and get their counts. Then end result should be a `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>`. However, with the code above, the compiler is saying that the `collect()` returns a  `ConcurrentMap <Object, ConcurrentMap<Object, Long>>`.

Why are the keys not Strings?

Comment: the result of `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>` does not seem to match your requirement. Why not a simple `Map<String, Long>` to count the occurrences of strings inside the file? Isn't this the requirement?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I'm trying to group by 2 keys here, so it's a nested map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can duplicate this error message, but the replacement of `String` with `Object` in the error message appears to be a red herring.  The real problem is that Java's generics are invariant.

If the call to `collect` is returning a `ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Long>>`, that doesn't match `Map<String, Map<String, Long>>`, even though a `ConcurrentMap` is a `Map`.  The inner `Map` type must match exactly without a wildcard and bounds.

If you introduce an upper-bounded wildcard to the return type, it will compile without error.  Have it return the type `Map<String, ? extends Map<String, Long>>`, so that the inner `ConcurrentMap<String, Long>` will match.

A return type of `Map<String, ConcurrentMap<String, Long>>` will also work.

It's unclear why `String` wasn't captured until the generics invariant issue was worked out.  Just a guess: the compiler didn't capture `String` yet, because it found the invariant generics issue first.  Once the invariant generics issue is resolved, it compiles without error, implying `String` does get inferred.